# Create Auto adjustable divs based on mouse over behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've been looking all over and seen a couple of similar posts but nothing that truly answers my question.  I want to be able to resize divs and the content within it similar to the style of the new [lafitness.com website](https://www.lafitness.com/Pages/Default.aspx).  I notice they are using silverlight for this function. I was curious if anyone knew how to do this in Javascript?  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It's quite an irritating feature - does it really add business value or are you doing it because it looks cool?

Comment: Agree with the assessment of the effect, but you could probably accomplish much, if not all of this with the jQuery animate method. [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/03/understanding-jquery-animate-function.html)

Answer (score 0):

That effect is awful...

however here is something similar in javascript that came to mind

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html